# Minimum iOS version for retina 4" support

Tags: iphone, ios, retina-display

Is there any minimum iOS version restrictions on using full-sized retina 4" screen? May I just use autoresizing masks and iOS 6 SDK for building an app with deployment target < iOS 6, which will run fullscreen on new retina display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building an app that takes advantage of the 4" screen requires Xcode 4.5 with a Base SDK of 6.0. The Deployment Target can be anything from 4.3 on up to 6.0. You just need to add the new Default.png specific to the 4" screen. Do this on the Summary tab of your project target. That's it. As long as your code properly sizes itself to the screen (regardless of its size) then your app will do what it is supposed to do.

Comment: @dieworld And of course be sure you test your app on the different devices to be sure your app works as expected.